# Name mangling in MASM (ML64) is inconsistent

Tags: masm

With the following file and using the Microsoft assembler ML64 (v14.00.2410.0, that ships with VS 2015), the assembler is mangling the name of the first routine (asm_cli) by adding an underscore, but it doesn't mangle the name of the second routine (asm_diable_vm). Why? The listing file doesn't show the name mangling, but LINK/DUMP on the .OBJ file shows the addition of the underscore.

Partial output from LINK/DUMP

```
RELOCATIONS #3
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000070  SECREL                     00000000         C  $$000000
 00000074  SECTION                        0000         C  $$000000
 00000225  SECREL                     00000000         A  _asm_cli
 00000229  SECTION                        0000         A  _asm_cli
 00000259  SECREL                     00000000         B  asm_disable_vm
 0000025D  SECTION                        0000         B  asm_disable_vm

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 01035E92 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000010 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .text$mn
    Section length   25, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
004 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .data
    Section length    0, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .debug$S
    Section length  274, #relocs    6, #linenums    0, checksum        0
008 00000000 SECT4  notype       Static       | .debug$T
    Section length   34, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00A 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    External     | _asm_cli
00B 00000010 SECT1  notype ()    External     | asm_disable_vm
00C 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | $$000000
```

Assembly.asm

```
cr0_pg          EQU     80000000h               ; Paging bit. If set, enables paging (and uses CR3 as pointer to page tables)
cr4_pae         EQU     20H                     ; Physical Address Extension. If set, uses extended page table size

;
;   Declare an C-callable entry point
;

routine_start   MACRO Name, Section
Section SEGMENT PARA 'CODE'
    DB      6 DUP (0ccH)                        ; Padding required by the calling standard
    ALIGN   16

    PUBLIC  Name
Name    PROC FRAME
.ENDPROLOG
ENDM

;
;   Declare the end of a routine
;

routine_end MACRO Name, Section
Name    ENDP
Section ENDS
ENDM


routine_start   asm_cli, _TEXT

        CLI                                     ; Disable interrupts
        RET

routine_end     asm_cli, _TEXT



routine_start   asm_disable_vm, _TEXT

        ;
        ; Disable paging
        ;

        MOV         RAX, CR0                    ; Get the contents of control register 0
        AND         EAX, 7fffffffH              ; Clear the paging bit
        MOV         CR0, RAX                    ; Save back to the register

        ;
        ; Empty the Translation Look-aside Buffer (TLB) by clearing the address of the 
        ; first-level page table
        ;

        XOR         RAX, RAX                    ; Clear EAX
        MOV         CR3, RAX                    ; Clear Control Register 3

        ;
        ; Disable Physical Address Extension (PAE)
        ;

        MOV         RAX, CR4                    ; Get the contents of control register 4
        AND         AL, NOT cr4_pae             ; Clear the PAE bit
        MOV         CR4, RAX                    ; Save back to the register

        RET

routine_end     asm_disable_vm, _TEXT

END
```

Comment: Name _mangling_ isn't _consistent_? **gasp** But in all seriousness, why does this matter? What's the real problem behind the question? Otherwise, questions like this typically get answers along the lines of "Because that's how it was programmed. Duh."

Comment: Because, I'd like to know whether I'm doing something incorrect, so I can predict what name the assembler is going to use, without having to resort to LINK/DUMP every time I add a routine. From the tone of your comment, am I to infer that this one of many known problems with the assembler?

Comment: *"one of many known problems with the assembler"* What does that mean? What are all these supposed "known problems"?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I *cannot* repro what you describe using ML64 shipped with VS 2015 ("Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.00.24210.0"). `dumpbin /symbols` shows two public symbols in the object file with the names exactly as requested: `asm_cli` and `asm_disable_vm`. No leading underscores.

Comment: I added a dummy routine before the other two, and the name mangling stopped. I am at a loss to explain it

Comment: I didn't have a dummy routine or anything. I first started with a simplified version of your code that didn't use any macros, and after that worked, I literally copied and pasted your code as shown here. It was that latter test I was referencing in my above comment. I don't know what could be different about your system's configuration versus mine. If this was consistently reproducible, it would likely be a bug. This leading underscore is a C mangling technique in 32-bit builds to indicate the calling convention. It doesn't make any sense for x86-64, as there is only one calling convention.

Comment: I think it is pretty clearly a bug. I'm giving up on Microsoft and switching to NASM. Thank you all for your help